# send output of two bolts to a single bolt in Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

What is the easiest way to send output of BoltA and BoltB to BoltC. Do I have to use Joins or is there any simpler solution. A and B have same fields (ts, metric_name, metric_count).

```
    // KafkaSpout --> LogDecoder
    builder.setBolt(LOGDECODER_BOLT_ID, logdecoderBolt, 10).shuffleGrouping(KAFKA_SPOUT_ID);

    // LogDecoder --> CountBolt
    builder.setBolt(COUNT_BOLT_ID, countBolt, 10).shuffleGrouping(LOGDECODER_BOLT_ID);

    // LogDecoder --> HttpResCodeCountBolt
    builder.setBolt(HTTP_RES_CODE_COUNT_BOLT_ID, http_res_code_count_bolt, 10).shuffleGrouping(LOGDECODER_BOLT_ID);


    # And now I want to send CountBolt and HttpResCodeCountBolt output to Aggregator Bolt.

    // CountBolt --> AggregatwBolt
    builder.setBolt(AGGREGATE_BOLT_ID, aggregateBolt, 5).fieldsGrouping((COUNT_BOLT_ID), new Fields("ts"));

    // HttpResCodeCountBolt --> AggregatwBolt
    builder.setBolt(AGGREGATE_BOLT_ID, aggregateBolt, 5).fieldsGrouping((HTTP_RES_CODE_COUNT_BOLT_ID), new Fields("ts"));
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Just add a stream-id ("stream1" and "stream2" below) to the fieldsGrouping call:

```
BoltDeclarer bd = builder.setBolt(AGGREGATE_BOLT_ID, aggregateBolt, 5); 
bd.fieldsGrouping((COUNT_BOLT_ID), "stream1",  new Fields("ts"));
bd.fieldsGrouping((HTTP_RES_CODE_COUNT_BOLT_ID), "stream2", new Fields("ts"));
```

and then in the execute() method for BoltC you can test to see which stream the tuple came from:

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

    if ("stream1".equals(tuple.getSourceStreamId())) {
        // this came from stream1
    } else if ("stream2".equals(tuple.getSourceStreamId())) {
        // this came from stream2
    }
```

Since you know which stream the tuple came from, you don't need to have the same shape of tuple on the two streams.  You just de-marshall the tuple according to the stream-id.

You can also check to see which component the tuple came from (as I type this I think this might be more appropriate to your case) as well as the instance of the component (the task) that emitted the tuple.

Comment: if you change your code like the above code, it will throw error like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bolt has already been declared for id

Comment: @Mouli I am getting the same error. Did you find the solution to it?

Comment: @Inderpal edited my answer to create a BoltDeclarer for the bolt and then use that reference to define the two input streams.  Not sure when this code stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris said you can use streams. But you can also simply get the source component from the tuple.

```
@Override
public final void execute(final Tuple tuple) {
    final String sourceComponent = tuple.getSourceComponent();
    ....
}
```

The source component is the name you gave to the Bolt at the topology's initialization. For instance: COUNT_BOLT_ID.